# SharePoint online - how to hide dropdown options based on usergroup current loggedin user belongs to

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online I have 3 groups named Employee, Manager, CEO and a list in SharePoint which has choice field named status. Status has 6 options.

Based on current logged in user's group I want to show only 2 options in dropdown out of 6 options. Like if user from Employee group adds item, he should be able to see only first 2 values in dropdown. If user from Manager group adds items, should be able to see only 3rd and 4th values in dropdown. If user from CEO group adds items, he should be able to see only last 2 options in dropdown.

Can someone help to acheive this using jquery or any other solutions?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013 Online list

Answer (score 3):

With a choice field, I doubt you can do this.

However, if you use a lookup list and then lock down the item permissions to the Employee Group, or Manager Group, or CEO group, then only them options would appear to that user when in the other list.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How to assign group for each item? Could you please tell how to lock down item permissions based on groups.